# wiring 3-speed outdoor ceiling fan/light with one switch and remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

Three-speed fan with receiver and remote, one wall switch and remote.  When the switch is on, I'm wanting to control the fan speed and light with the remote.

From ceiling:

- There's copper (bare), red, white, black.

From fan:

- there's black, white, blue.

From receiver:

- there's "out" black, white, blue
- there's "in" black, white

Suggestions on how to wire to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the red from the ceiling is controlled by the switch, connect it to the receiver "in" black. Connect the white from the ceiling to the white "in" from the receiver. Take the receiver black "out" and connect it to the fan black, the white "out" from the receiver to the fan white and the blue "out" from the receiver to the fan blue.  Don't forget to connect your grounds, bare copper from ceiling to green wires from fan/receiver. Cap the black from the ceiling.